# get text of anchor tag and display it in html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm using the below code and its working fine for me, for one anchor tag.

```
<h1 id="h1">heading</h1>
<a type="button" id="demo" onclick="Func()">sign-up</a>
```

***JS***

```
function Func() {
    document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "sign-up";
}
```

**How to do this for 3 or 4 anchor tags ?**

**What I actually want is everytime when clicked on anchor tags get its text and display it in the only one `<h1></h1>` tag**

Any answer will be appreciated either **JS** or **JQuery**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try JQuery like

your h1 tag like

```
<h1 id="anchorText"> </h1>
```

and your anchor tags like

```
<a type="button" id="demo">sign-up</a>
<a type="button" id="demo1" >Login</a>
```

Now in your jquery

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#anchorText").text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: type button for anchor and giving so much `id` is inefficient coding practice

Comment: we are not using button id if you can see in jquery its just for understanding the questioner

Answer (score 2):

You can add `class` to all the links and based on that add a click event handler for them.

```js
$(".buttons").click(e => $("#h1").text(e.currentTarget.textContent));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="h1">heading</h1>
<a type="button" class="buttons">sign-up</a>
<a type="button" class="buttons">sign-in</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` in the `Func()` to refer to the clicked element and then get the `innerHTML` (or innerText) of that element based on your convenience.

```js
function Func(e) {
  document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">heading</h1>
<a type="button" id="demo1" onclick="Func(this)">sign-up</a>
<a type="button" id="demo2" onclick="Func(this)">sign-in</a>
```